# Renaming System Folder - Creates reload loop

Tags: htaccess

I wanted to rename my system folder. But when I do so and point my browser to the new cp url I create a infinite reload loop and chrome goes nuts.

- Renamed system folder ***Check***
- Renamed system url in admin.php and index.php ***Check***

I've done it x times on the same environment and suddenly this loop error appears.

In my .htaccess I have the new remove index.php directives from the ellislab blog

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

First I thought this could be the error but it also doesn't work with the old index.php removal code.

Anybody experienced the same behavior?

EE v 2.72
PHP : 5.5.3

Comment: Have you tried it without any rewriting? Also, you say that Chrome goes nuts when you point it at your cp url, but isn't that still admin.php? Is the system folder above the root?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
```

line in htaccess to match the new system folder name:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/new_system_folder_name/.* [NC]
```